# Strategy to solve a variety of nice (and hard) integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Ive been stuck almost an hour trying to solve this integral

$$ \int\limits_{- \infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{ x^2 e^x }{( 1 + e^{7x} )^2 } dx $$

which is ${\bf convergent}$. I tried to do

$$ \int\limits_{- \infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{ x^2 e^x }{( 1 + e^{7x} )^2 } dx = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{ e^ x }{(1+e^{7x})} dx \int_0^x 2y dy$$

But, I dont see any "improvement" from there. Perhaps complex analysis may help, but I am trying to hopefully find a solution that is as elementary as possible. I was considering perhaps to look at

$$ \int\limits_{- \infty}^{\infty}  \dfrac{ x^2 e^x }{(1+e^{ax} )^2} dx$$

for any $a>0$. Is this a well-known integral? Can someone help me solve this or pinpoint me into relevant literature?

Comment: How do you get the improved form ??

Comment: @metamorphy: and the second integral lies inside the other !

Comment: Your title is misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be related to the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). The last integral converges for $a>1/2$ and equals
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2 e^x\,dx}{(1+e^{ax})^2}\underset{ax=t}{=}\frac{1}{a^3}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{t^2 e^{t/a}\,dt}{(1+e^t)^2}=\frac{1}{a^3}f''\Big(\frac1a\Big),\qquad\text{where}\\f(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{at}\,dt}{(1+e^t)^2}\underset{e^t=x}{=}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{a-1}\,dx}{(1+x)^2}=\mathrm{B}(a,2-a)=\frac{\pi(1-a)}{\sin\pi a}$$ (for $a=1$, the last formula should be interpreted as the limit, equal to $1$ of course).